# Python hunspell package installation via pip fails

Tags: python, pip, hunspell

The installation of the hunspell python package (via pip) fails with the following error:

```
hunspell.c:21:22: fatal error: hunspell.h: No such file or directory
 #include <hunspell.h>
                      ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Any idea what to do to solve this?

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install libhunspell-dev
pip install hunspell
```

...as recommended in the same thread in pyhunspell's github page (provided by John D):  https://github.com/blatinier/pyhunspell/issues/22

I couldn't install 'hunspell-dev', but I could install libhunspell-dev.

Answer (score 1):

Try 
`sudo apt-get install hunspell-dev` 
and then try installing hunspell (or pyhunspell) again

This problem is referenced in an issue on pyhuspell's github page:
https://github.com/blatinier/pyhunspell/issues/22

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
sudo apt-get install libhunspell-dev
python3 -m pip install hunspell
```

or use this

https://pypi.org/project/CyHunspell/